# How do i build a custom build with an older revision(svn) than in teamcity registered?

Tags: svn, teamcity, custom-build, teamcity-6

I have an older revision "1xx" in SVN, which I would like to run with TeamCity via custom-build.
The TeamCity project was not established until the revision of 2xx, so that I can choose when you custom build only the revisions to 2xx.
How do I find the revision in the 1xx custom build?

Comment: You can create brunch (tag) and use it. But this is not good solution

Comment: The solution I do not even beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this is not possible, please watch/vote for following issues: [TW-9832](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-9832), [TW-11400](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-11400).

Comment: Thank you for the answers, too bad that it is not yet implemented.